# Measure of similarity between boolean formulas?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Apologies, if this is a *dumb* question...

Is there a measure of structural *similarity* between Boolean formulas A and B, such that if we know some information about A's behavior under a set of inputs $I_A$ then we can assign some degree of likelihood that B will manifest some behavior (not necessarily the same) under $I_A$?

Comment: It might help to define what you mean by structural similarity. How do you rule out simply evaluating $B$ on the inputs of interest?

Comment: _Structural_ similarity of boolean expressions is not easily related to _functional_ similarity. Very different expressions can have identical behavior, and very similar expressions can have drastically different behaviors. Were this not so, many fundamental computability results would be quite different. Compare for example Rice's theorem.

Comment: It does occur to me that if you have $\land$ and $\lor$ only, you can at least conclude that your functions are monotonic. Is that the kind of result you are looking for?

Comment: @MJD I am looking for properties that I can use to group formulas based on their behavior, e.g. If I choose sets of inputs that make A behave a certain way and I invoke B with those inputs, B will behave in a predictable way. As per Karl's comment, perhaps structural properties are not those that make sense, but are there any that do?

Comment: And you want properties that can be efficiently computed from syntactic representations, right? It might help to quantify that requirement (e.g. polynomial time?) and also to clarify your notion of functional similarity/predictability (maybe information-theoretically?).

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information), viewing each boolean expression as a random variable on a space of possible inputs.